# Embed the collections using mongodb

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I am just start using mongodb and nodejs. I know that mongodb does not supports joins.I simply insert the data in mongodb and my documents looks:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("564dacf84d52785c1d8b4567"),
    "content": "This blog created by karanSofat",
   "html": "<p>This blog created by karanSofat</p>\n",
}
```

Now user comments on this post. it should be like this:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("564dacf84d52785c1d8b4567"),
   "comments": [
     {
       "name": "sumit",
       "email": "sumit@ggi.net",
       "comment": "this is also well for me",
       "posted_at": ISODate("2015-11-19T11:06:27.172Z") 
    } 
  ],
   "content"▼: "This blog created by karanSofat",
   "html": "<p>This blog created by karanSofat</p>\n", 
}
```

Here is my models,

```
   //post model
// grab the mongoose module
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// define our nerd model
// module.exports allows us to pass this to other files when it is called
module.exports = mongoose.model('post', {
    content : {type : String, default: ''},
    html : {type : String, default: ''}


});
//comment model
 var mongoose = require('mongoos
      module.exports = mongoose.model('comment', {
        name : {type : String, default: ''},
        email : {type : String, default: ''},
        comment : {type : String, default: ''},
        posted_at : {type : date, default: ''}

    });
```

My Problem is that I don't know on which way I insert comments data using nodejs and my document will embed.
Here is my code:

```
app.post('/comments/:id', function(req, res) {
var Comment = require("../app/models/comments");//comment Model
var blog = require("../app/models/blog");//blog model

var id = req.params.id; //postId
var comments = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body)); //commentdata

//code Should be here

res.json({data:id,data2:input});
});
```

Please help

Comment: are you using mongoose? or mongodb module?

Comment: @ inspired: I am using mongoose...

Comment: Please post the schema for `../app/models/comments` and `../app/models/blog`.

Comment: @ inspired: I update my question...

Comment: @ inspired : I solved this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Karan,

Let's assume you have the following schema:

```
var Comments = new Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    comment: String,
  , posted_at: Date
});

var BlogPost = new Schema({
  content     : String,
  html      : String,
  comments  : [Comments],
});

mongoose.model('BlogPost', BlogPost);
```

You can add an embed document to an array as such:

```
// retrieve my model
var BlogPost = mongoose.model('BlogPost');

// create a blog post
var post = new BlogPost();

// create a comment
post.comments.push({
   "name": "sumit",
   "email": "sumit@ggi.net",
   "comment": "this is also well for me",
   "posted_at": ISODate("2015-11-19T11:06:27.172Z") 
});

post.save(function (err) {
  if (!err) console.log('Success!');
});
```

Comment: In my case  there is many posts and user comment on that posts. I want to relate comments wit the posts.